# Discord.py on guild leave

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I was wondering if it is possible for a bot to send a message when the bot has been removed from a server, so far I have this and it hasn't worked

````
async def on_guild_leave(guild):
channel = client.get_channel(993919891902042197)
await channel.send(f"bot has left name: {guild.name}, owner: {guild.owner}, guild owner ID: {guild.owner.id}, guild ID:{guild.id} and we have {len(client.guilds)} servers")```
````

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Did you add the appropriate decorator? Did you enable the required intents?

Comment: Make sure its an event. Make sure you use the correct decorators. Make sure you have enabled the correct intents. Make sure that the bot is in the server with the given Channel ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct event is `on_guild_remove()`.

Please read https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_remove for more information on the event.

The working code would be like this:

```py
async def on_guild_remove(guild):
    # do something...
```

Take note that `Intents.guilds` must be enabled in order for this event to be detected, as stated in the documentation linked above.